# Find the pdf of Y = 1/X and compute E(Y)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let the random variable have a pdf $f_X(x) = 2x$ when $0<x<1$ and $0$ otherwise. 
Let the random variable $Y=1/X$. Find the pdf of $Y$ and use it to calculate $E(Y)$.

The pdf of $Y$ is $f_Y(y) = \frac{2}{y^3}$. What is the support for $f_Y(y)$?

Comment: $0<x<1$, and $y=1/x$. What's the range of $y$?And it seems that your question is unclear to me.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to do in such a problem is to figure out the
support of the random variable $Y$, which is $(1, \infty).$
To find it, try several values of $x$ in $(0, 1)$ and see what 
happens. You were right to ask about this crucial issue.

Your text probably shows transformation methods based on the CDF
and on the PDF. An abbreviated version of the former (with gaps for you to complete) is as follows:

$$ F_Y(t) = P(Y \le t) = P(1/X \le t) = P(X \ge 1/t)\\ = 1 - P(X \le 1/t) = 1 - 1/t^2,$$

for $t$ in the support of $Y$.

Then, by differentiation, the 
PDF of $Y$ is $f_Y(t) = 2t^{-3},$ as you say.
Finally, $E(Y) = \int_1^\infty 2t^{-3} \, dt = 2.$
[Some of this is in your Question, and some is in @drhab's
succinct Answer (+1)]

If you recognize that $X \sim Beta(2, 1),$ then it is easy to do
a quick simulation in R to check this answer (correct to
two or three decimal places based on a million simulated
values of $Y$):

```
 x = rbeta(10^6, 2, 1);  y = 1/x;  mean(y)
 ## 2.001900  # aprx of E(Y)
```

Below is a histogram of 10,000 simulated values of $Y$
along with a plot of the PDF of $Y$. This distribution
is extremely right-skewed, with a long tail to the right.
The scale of the histogram extends out to about 60 in recognition of
occasional scattered points too sparsely spread to
make histogram bars of noticeable height. (The biggest
of the 10,000 values plotted in this histogram was at 57.44494.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you explain how you recognized this to be a Beta(2,1) distribution?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the data we find: $$F_{X}\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }x\leq0\\
x^{2} & \text{if }0<x<1\\
1 & \text{if }x\geq1\end{cases}$$

Based on that we find: $$F_{Y}\left(y\right)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }y\leq1\\
1-y^{-2} & \text{if }y>1\end{cases}$$

Then $f_Y$ prescribed by: $$y\mapsto\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }y\leq1\\
2y^{-3} & \text{if }y>1\end{cases}$$serves as PDF (it is the derivative of the CDF).

Comment: The derivative of $x = 1/y$ is $-1/y^2$. What happened to the negative sign?

Comment: @Christina I do not understand. Where in my answer did I take the derivative of $1/y$? I did take the derivative of $1-y^{-2}$ and concluded correctly that it is $2y^{-3}$.

Comment: In fact I always use the chain rule. For example $f_Y(y) = f_X(x).\frac{dx}{dy}$. For example here for $\frac{dx}{dy}$ it will be $\frac{-1}{y^2}$. And $f_X(x)$ will be $\frac{2}{y}$ if we write it in terms of y. So how to avoid the negative sign we have for $\frac{dx}{dy}$ ?

Comment: @Christina I cannot find any link between my answer and what you are saying in your comment. In my answer $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary variables without any connection so it makes no sense to say things about $\frac{dx}{dy}$.

Comment: Please just watch this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXwPUAIvFyg) from 7:40 to 20:20. Can you please after clarify more for me? thank you alot

Comment: And even here they explain this: https://www.math.arizona.edu/~jwatkins/f-transform.pdf. In page 2. I understand now I think it is something related to functions which are decreasing or non decreasing.

Comment: @Christina It is explained that by a suitable funcion $g$ for $Y=g\left(X\right)$ we
find $f_{Y}\left(y\right)=\left|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}\left(y\right)\right|f_{X}\left(g^{-1}\left(y\right)\right)$. Also see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables). 
Applying that on the question that was asked this results in $\left|-y^{-2}\right|\frac{2}{y}=\frac{2}{y^{3}}$. Note that we deal with absolute value. I suspect you overlooked that.

Comment: exactly I forgot the absolute value. Now we have to use an absolute value and of course we will end up with $|\frac{dx}{dy}| >0$. Thank you for your time drhab!!

Comment: @Christina I did not use that method, but first found the CDF of $Y$. After that I took its derivative.

Comment: yes but I think using the chain rule is the simplest method no? You can solve the exercise with only one equality!

Comment: @Christina Let's call it a matter of taste. Cheers!

Comment: Yesss.. Cheers!